# Trouble installing XCGLogger swift_2.0

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, xcglogger

I am trying to install XCGLogger Swift 2.0 using xcode7.4 beta using cocoapods.

Here is my pod file.

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'City Summer School' do
    pod 'Firebase', '>= 2.3.3'
    pod 'XCGLogger', :git => 'https://github.com/DaveWoodCom/XCGLogger.git', :branch => 'swift_2.0'
end

target 'City Summer SchoolTests' do
    pod 'Firebase', '>= 2.3.3'
    pod 'XCGLogger', :git => 'https://github.com/DaveWoodCom/XCGLogger.git', :branch => 'swift_2.0'
end
```

Yet when I try and compile I get this error.

```
error: /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/otool: can't open file: /Users/nim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/City_Summer_School-cwdihbtsferehfbcdcilbmzrnqbp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/City Summer School.app/Frameworks/XCGLogger.framework/XCGLogger (No such file or directory)
```

Have I missed something in the install?

**To add additional information**

I ran pod install, from the terminal after I configured my Podfile which added to my already existing xcworkspace file.

In the project settings under Linked Frameworks and Libraries?

Pods_City_Summer_School.framework was listed as required.

This is a conversion from Swift 1 --> Swift 2.0

Comment: FYI, you should probably use the `master` branch now. I've merged the Swift 2 code to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're leaving out a lot of missing information about your setup. I actually just installed XCGLogger tonight in a new Swift 2 project and it works.

1. Did you open xcode with the workspace file generated by 'pod install' and build from there? You have to use the workspace, not the "old" project file.
2. Is the pod framework set as optional in your project (not the pod project) settings under Linked Frameworks and Libraries?

Comment: I have added more details into the question, I rebuilt  it from scratch just now and it worked so there must be something todo with the conversion that is causing the issues...

Comment: There was an issue with my version of Cocoapods on the latest beta of El Capitan... I have resolved this issue now.

Answer (score 0):

### Colorful Logging Swift 2

In case you still have issues installing and you are still in the need of a lightweight, fast & feature-rich Logger which can be installed via Carthage then maybe try SwiftyBeaver https://github.com/skreutzberger/SwiftyBeaver instead